# Creating a tensor of rank $k$ from elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list containing $4^k$ elements, how do I create a "square" $\underbrace{4\times...\times4}_{k\text{-times}}$ tensor of rank $k$?

Intuitively, I would opt for the `ArrayReshape` function. However, I am unsure how to proceed given the variable number of the tensor rank.

In case of $k=2$, we would have

```
tensor = ArrayReshape[list, {4,4}]
```

How do I generalize this function to the case of some arbitrary rank $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`ConstantArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html)

```
k = 3;
tensor = ArrayReshape[list, ConstantArray[4, k]]
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly!
Thank you so much